# How to add weight for each training example while training in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

i'm trying to add weight for each observation while training.
Depending on how difficult this observation.
Note: i'm using fit_generator

I'have tried to build a new generator, which generate (x,y,weight)

```py
def ensembleCategoricalGenerator(generator, nBatches, batchSize):
    i = 0
    while i < nBatches:
        train_x, train_y = generator[i]
        yhat = classifier.predict(train_x)
        yTrue =  train_y[:, np.newaxis] # convert shape (batchSize,) to (batchSize, 1)
        result = yTrue == yhat.round()
        nCorrect = result.sum()
        correctWeight, incorrectWeight = .5/nCorrect, .5/(batchSize-nCorrect)
        weights = np.array([correctWeight if oneResult else incorrectWeight for oneResult in result])
        yield (train_x, train_y, weights)
        i = i + 1
#### End
ensembleGenerator = ensembleCategoricalGenerator(trainIterator,len(trainIterator), batchSize)
print(type(ensembleGenerator))
print(type(trainIterator))
```

Output :-

```
class 'generator'  
class 'keras_preprocessing.image.dataframe_iterator.DataFrameIterator'
```

I expected fit_generator to accept my generator but this didn't work.